# Is there an alternate way to trigger autocorrect/autocomplete on mobile Safari (on iOS) when the user presses enter?

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile-safari, contenteditable, autocorrect

I know that normally the browser will handle autocorrect/capitalization/etc on its own when the user presses enter. But I'm using the contenteditable attribute and doing some special handling on "enter" that requires me to use evt.preventDefault() when the user presses enter. Since I'm using preventDefault() in my listener, mobile safari leaves the autocorrect bubble open and it gets pretty funky looking/unusable. Is there any alternate way (maybe using JS to fire an event) to dismiss the bubble or trigger the normal behavior without having to take out preventDefault?

I don't want to get rid of autocorrect functionality, since it is important to my application.

Comment: More generally, when iOS is displaying a proposed autocorrection for an input value on screen, is there a way to get the value after autocorrection for use in javascript?

Comment: You may use `onfocus` `onblur` etc in your contenteditable div.

Answer (score 0):

**There should be sample code!** But I think you talk of something like this:

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Do other stuff
});
```

So I'm pretty sure you could fire the [`.blur`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/)-event manually which could fire that autocomplete-function:

```
$("#myForm #myInput").blur();
```

If this answer is wrong, please provide sample code - not everybody on Stackoverflow is a magician.

Comment: I don't know what the original poster's code looked like, but if I have a `keypress` handler with an `event.preventDefault` call, adding a adding a `blur` before the `event.preventDefault` doesn't get me the corrected text: http://jsfiddle.net/LGWrJ/

Answer (score 0):

I will say its easy with focus set, 
in contrast to previous answer which works with submit the auto behavior will continue to auto correct..

```
$("#MyInput").focus(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
$("#MyInput").blur(){ // do events you want on focus lost.. from input.. :)
});
```

I think this will do..